# "Subscript Indices" error in Octave, but no subscripts being used?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am attempting to calculate the numeric value of the derivative of a function using Octave, but I keep getting this error:

> error: fp: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals

This error is strange, because I am not using subscript indices anywhere in my code. Here is the function `fp` that throws the error:

```
function [ dy ] = fp(f, x, ep)  
    dy = (f(x .+ ep) .- f(x)) ./ ep;  
end
```

The function works when I run it from the Octave interpreter, but when I try to call the function using the file `fp.m` I get the above error. This is the function I am passing to it:

```
function [ y ] = f(x)
    y = (x .+ 2) .* x .+ 1;
end
```

I've tried renaming all the variables in `fp` on the off chance that I had stumbled upon a reserved variable name. Any other ideas?

Comment: do you have a variable named fp somewhere in your file? a file pointer perhaps?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do not. The above is all the contents of my two files, named fp.m and f.m, respectively. I haven't started writing main.m yet, because I wanted to get these working first. :-\ However, I did wonder if I had named even the file wrong, and temporarily changed its name to derivative.

Comment: You said you get the error when you call fp from a file. Can you please show that file?

Comment: I mean calling the function `fp` that is in fp.m. When I type the assignment statement into the interpreter it runs. When I call the function (saved in the file) it throws the error. Sorry for the misunderstanding; I am not calling it from a different file yet.

Comment: Hmmm. Show me the two different invocations please. I think I may know what the problem is.

Comment: When I call the assignment from the interpreter it looks like this:
dy = (f(-5 .+ 1.0e-15) .- f(-5)) ./ 1.0e-15
When I call it from its file it looks like this:
fp("f", -5, 1.0e-15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave has function pointers similar to those in C, except they are called function handles. Here is how you should invoke the file version:

```
fp(@f, -5, 1.0e-15);
```

If you pass in `"f"`, it is just a character array. In this case, the expression `f(...)` inside `fp` is interpreted as an indexing expression into a char array because `fp` is not seeing a function handle. If you pass in `@f`, that is a pointer to a function that `fp` can invoke directly.

Comment: I should have asked this question three days ago. Thank you so much. Google has been no help at all.

Comment: I can see that. I would recommend the searching the MathWorks MATLAB documentation. It's responsible for 90% of my MATLAB expertise. The rest is just knowing how to covert MATLAB to Octave...

Comment: I hadn't thought to look at the Matlab documentation. Thank you for that, too!